# Tag suggestions "animal models" and "research"

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17580/is-there-a-superterm-combining-animal-line-and-cell-line-in-disease-models) about the terminology in animal models of disease, and had lots of trouble finding tags. There were [computational-models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-models) and [mathematical-models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-models), but no [disease-models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disease-models) or [animal-models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-models) or [translational-models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translational-models) or [preclinical-models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preclinical-models) or [animal-lines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-lines) or [cell-lines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-lines). I think that the site can use at least one of my "models" suggestion, and I would leave it to the community here to decide which one is best.

Second, I used the tag [research](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) mostly out of desperation, but I don't think it is a very good tag. It is a word which can be understood very differently in different contexts, and in my experience, this makes it a bad tag. I used it because preclinical models are a tool in biology research. But [the only other question which uses it](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17571/how-does-a-biologist-decide-when-she-has-enough-results-to-publish-a-paper) is about the daily academic life of a biology scientist, which is a different use. I also anticipate that it will someday be used in non-constructive ways: somebody can construe it as to be used when a question asks "is there research on the topic I want to ask about", which is probably true of most questions on the site. Another problem would if a user thinks "I am doing research (= seeking more information) on X, so I will tag my question with X and research" - this certainly covers 100% of the question on the site and completely defeats the purpose of the tag.

My suggestion would be to rename, and maybe split, the research tag into something like [research-tools](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-tools) and [research-process](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-process), or any more suitable expressions.

Answer (score 3):

I think [animal-models](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-models) is a good tag, and I have added that to your question. I agree that [research](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) is too vague. I followed your suggestion and split it. Feel free to add wiki summaries for all three.

Comment: Note that [tag: animal model] may be confused with the statistical model used in genetics and evolutionary ecology called *animal model* (see e.g. [An ecologist's guide to the animal model](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20409158)). A clear tag description might therefore be needed.